# Generate a tree in javascript IE8 takes too much time

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm using mktree.js to generate tree,
source: http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/mktree/source.html
When i run it in Chrome or IE9 it takes +/- 15 Seconds for 25MB of data
In IE8 which is the standard the run time is arround 240 Seconds.

Any idea how to optimize this or is there setting in IE8 to configure or an alternative to mkTree.js?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/) and is very fast to load tree with many nodes.

You can see if that is an alternate to mkTree. I moved away from mkTree as it behaves differently is different browsers and also due to performance issues.